# On click on add button add another radio button with input box value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi guys i have form where i want to show multiple radio buttons.so by default i am showing one radio button with text and gave option as Addother button ..so user can add multiple radio buttons onclick on add option button as per their requirement..

So here is what i have tried.

**Answer Section:**

```
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="add_other">
              <div id="container0">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked" name="defaultExampleRadios">
                <input type="search" name="" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio" >
              <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked" name="defaultExampleRadios">
              <input type="search" name="" value="">
              <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
             <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked" name="defaultExampleRadios">
             <input type="search" name="" value="">
             <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
           </div>
           <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
             <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked" name="defaultExampleRadios">
             <input type="search" name="" value="">
             <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
           </div>
           <div class="custom-control copy-radio" onclick="addoptions()">
              <label class="add_option" id="add_othe1r">Add More</label>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Script code:

```
var index = 3;

  function addoptions() {
    $('#add_other').append(`<div id="container${index}" >` + '<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="defaultExampleRadios"/ >'  + `<input type="search" name="text"/>` +  "</div>");
    index ++;
  }
function removeDiv(btn){
    ((btn.parentNode).parentNode).removeChild(btn.parentNode);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set 3 new containers inside id of "add_other" container.

```js
function addoptions() {
  $('#add_other').append('<div>' + '<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="defaultExampleRadios">' + '<input type="search" name="" value="">' + '<button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>' + "</div>");
}

function removeDiv(btn) {
  ((btn.parentNode).parentNode).removeChild(btn.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="add_other">
  <div id="container0">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="defaultExampleRadios">
    <input type="search" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input"  name="defaultExampleRadios">
    <input type="search" name="" value="">
    <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="defaultExampleRadios">
    <input type="search" name="" value="">
    <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="defaultExampleRadios">
    <input type="search" name="" value="">
    <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="custom-control copy-radio" onclick="addoptions()">
  <label class="add_option" id="add_othe1r">Add More</label>
</div>
```

Comment: its working..how can i apply that same removediv function for add more radio buttons also

Answer (score 1):

You set the id `add_other` to the Add Option button container. You need to remove that and reset the id to the first `div` container

```js
var index = 1;

function addoptions() {
  $('#add_other').append(`<div id="container${index}" >` + '<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="defaultExampleRadios"/>' + `<input type="search" name="text" onsearch="deleteRadio(${index})"/>` + "</div>");
  index ++;
}

function deleteRadio(ind) {
  $(`#container${ind}`).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidden_radio_buttons" class="radio_buttons" style="margin:10px;">
  <!-- Default unchecked -->
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="add_other">
    <div id="container0">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked" name="defaultExampleRadios">
      <input type="search" name="" value="" placeholder="option 1" onsearch="deleteRadio(0)">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Default unchecked -->
  <div class="custom-control copy-radio" onclick="addoptions()">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="defaultExampleRadios">
    <label class="add_option" id="add_othe1r">Add Option</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224517/discussion-on-answer-by-william-wang-on-click-on-add-button-add-another-radio-bu).